# How can I implement Claims-Based Identity Implementation in MVC4.0 Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity

Additionaly I have to implement authorization in such a way like for example owner of the organisation is asking for that I need to provide all information. If some team member is asking for the same information with his claims then I need to provide him lesser information than owner. And if some third party or external user is asking for the same information then I need to provide him very few information although they all are authenticated and authorized but the amount of information provided is different. Similar to Facebook like concept. Your friends can see more information about you but lesser than yourself but more than acquaintances.